# Code not getting hot swapped in emulator

Tags: android

everything was working fine, suddenly hot swap of code is not working. 
after i change anything in the code and rebuild and launch, console flashes this error:

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR Please check logcat
>   output for more details. Launch canceled!

here is the logcat: 
[image]

I have to again and again resstart emulator to see my changes! I have tried restarting adb, wipe user data but :(

Comment: IDK why the downvote, but try reinstalling the android SDK and the ADT plugin.

Comment: @Rob Oh i wont go that far for this.,that will be too much of work :/

Comment: Im using new emulator, but dont know what was the problem with that one :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok  from the logcat as it says could not delete "some" file, i went to the file explorer and deleted that file manually. Works now! ;)